# Postgres: suspend the connection but keep the transaction

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, transactions, database-connection

Take the case that a group of modifies on DB is intervallated by some services calls, and i don't want to retain the connection in meanwhile, is there a way to suspend the transaction and resume it after the services have respond?

Comment: No there is not, a transaction is derived from a connection. Once you drop the connection you lose the transaction.

Comment: Run the "service calls" in a second database connection.